# img tag not showing background image only in FireFox

Tags: css, image, firefox

I have a gallery of images, and the images display fine on all other browsers (IE, Chrome, O, Saf) but refuses to show on firefox.
The image is displayed like this:

```
<section class="p-0" id="portfolio">
    <div class="container-fluid p-0">
        <div class="row no-gutters popup-gallery">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                <a class="portfolio-box" href="http://apache.techgorilla.io/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/ckG9Q85.png">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="" style="background-image: url(http://apache.techgorilla.io/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/ckG9Q85.png);" alt="">
                    <div class="portfolio-box-caption">
                        <div class="portfolio-box-caption-content">
                            <div class="project-category text-faded">
                                Web
                            </div>
                            <div class="project-name">
                                TechGorilla UI example site
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

I set src empty as I have a background image. The CSS for that is the following:

```
.portfolio-box {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.portfolio-box .img-fluid {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 300px;
    background-position: center center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    border:0;
}

.portfolio-box .portfolio-box-caption {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0;
    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(240, 95, 64, 0.9);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
    transition: all 0.2s;
}

.portfolio-box .portfolio-box-caption .portfolio-box-caption-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    text-align: center;
}

.portfolio-box .portfolio-box-caption .portfolio-box-caption-content .project-category,
.portfolio-box .portfolio-box-caption .portfolio-box-caption-content .project-name {
    padding: 0 15px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
}

.portfolio-box .portfolio-box-caption .portfolio-box-caption-content .project-category {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.portfolio-box .portfolio-box-caption .portfolio-box-caption-content .project-name {
    font-size: 18px;
}

.portfolio-box:hover .portfolio-box-caption {
    opacity: 1;
}

.portfolio-box:focus {
    outline: none;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .portfolio-box .portfolio-box-caption .portfolio-box-caption-content .project-category {
        font-size: 16px;
    }
    .portfolio-box .portfolio-box-caption .portfolio-box-caption-content .project-name {
        font-size: 22px;
    }
}
```

It will work fine everywhere else, its not an issue of the browser not finding certain variables (AKA needing -mos-transition etc) and I have a script that fixes that automatically anyway.

I have googled and have not found any similar issue, and I have used firefox/google/etc devtools to add/remove elements to try and get it working to no avail

Answer (score 1):

So it seems, unlike all other browsers, in FF you need to specify the 'display' property. simply adding

> display: block;

to the class

> .portfolio-box .img-fluid

Which will now show the images perfectly fine, I didnt try it earlier because I assumed it was inherited by default

Comment: img tag is inline-block by default.

Answer (score 0):

My intuition is that your omg tag has an empty `src` attribute. If you're going to just use the background to display the image, just use `div`

Comment: Thats sort of my worse-case-scenario but id rather only try it if theres no viable solution for the problem i posted

Comment: @Cacoon I think it would be more idiomatic if you either use the `src` attribute, or switch to a `div` tag. That way, you won't end up with any wonky side-effects.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, an alternative to putting the background image in the div is to change the img tag from:

```
<img class="img-fluid" src="" style="background-image: url(http://apache.techgorilla.io/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/ckG9Q85.png);" alt="">
```

to:

```
<img class="img-fluid" src="http://apache.techgorilla.io/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/ckG9Q85.png" alt="Tech Gorilla">
```

Now the page looks as I imagine you want it to look in Chrome, Firefox, and even IE 11.

Comment: It doesnt do the desired effect to the image with the background properties im afraid ):